# Pydantic: how to pass custom object to validators

Tags: pydantic

I wanted to use pydantic to validate messages sent by players in a turn based game.

For example, I want players to select a card that they want to play, and the validation is first, whether the card ID is correct at all, and then I want to validate if player has this card on hand.

Here's the code:

```
class SelectCardActionParams(BaseModel):
    selected_card: CardIdentifier  # just my enum

    @validator('selected_card')
    def player_has_card_on_hand(cls, v, values, config, field):
        # To tell whether the player has card on hand, I need access to my <GameInstance> object which tracks entire 
        # state of the game, has info on which player has which cards on hand. How do I pass this instance here? 
        pass
```

It seems like the "custom validation" feature lets me write code that can access only fields directly on the model instance, and nothing else, i.e. no access to any external state. It seems like a serious limitation of how validation can be used by programmers.

Am I missing something? I know the doc says that pydantic is mainly a parsing lib not a validation lib but it does have the "custom validation", and I thought there should be a way to pass custom arguments to the validator methods (I could not find any example though).

Comment: You question is very vague. What does "access external state" mean? What do you mean by "passing a custom object" to the validator? The validator is a method like any other. You can do whatever you want inside that method. The difference is the validator is not (intended to be) called by you directly. Since it is a classmethod, you can access anything else in the class' namespace inside the method. That being said, IMO validation should absolutely be self-contained on a per-model basis. You can of course have a field on that model referencing another model, if you want.

Comment: Hmm... I thought I put it very specific. Imagine you have this speficic example where your Pydantic model represents some action taken by a player e.g. playing a card, so let's say the model has two fields acting_player_id and selected_card_id. You'd like to validate if player with given ID has a card with given ID on hand. But that information is NOT on your model. It's in some other object (such as <Game> instance), so normally, what you'd do is just to call game_instance.player_has_card(player_id, card_id) but how can you call that function from inside validator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment did clarify your intention a bit. I think I understand what you are after now.

A Pydantic models defines a schema for some data. A validator enforces constraints on that data. As I said in my comment, a validator is a **class** method. It has no access to any instance of the model it is defined on, unless that instance is somehow present in the class' (or even the global) namespace. Aside from that, a validator (depending on the configuration) may have access to already validated values meant to be assigned to other fields of the model.

If you need some instance of `Game`, you can thus either assign one as a [class variable](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#automatically-excluded-attributes) to your `SelectCardActionParams` model or just make it globally available.

Then, since you need both values to be present and probably don't want to rely on which order they are defined it, it is probably easiest to just use a [`@root_validator`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/#root-validators).

It could look like this (simplified):

```py
from typing import Any, ClassVar
from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError, root_validator

class Game:
    def player_has_card(self, player_id: int, card_id: int) -> bool:
        return player_id == card_id  # just for demo purposes

game_singleton = Game()

class SelectCardActionParams(BaseModel):
    game: ClassVar[Game] = game_singleton
    acting_player_id: int
    selected_card_id: int

    @root_validator
    def player_has_card(cls, values: dict[str, Any]) -> dict[str, Any]:
        player_id = values["acting_player_id"]
        card_id = values["selected_card_id"]
        if not cls.game.player_has_card(player_id, card_id):
            raise ValueError(f"Player {player_id} has no card {card_id}")
        return values

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(SelectCardActionParams(acting_player_id=1, selected_card_id=1))
    try:
        SelectCardActionParams(acting_player_id=1, selected_card_id=2)
    except ValidationError as e:
        print(e)
```

The output:

```
acting_player_id=1 selected_card_id=1
1 validation error for SelectCardActionParams
__root__
  Player 1 has no card 2 (type=value_error)
```

Comment: Yeah, I guess everything can be achieved by making vars global and methods static. But I'm not sure I like it. It's not very object-oriented. In this case I realized I need to either use the pattern you proposed i.e. use global variable, or write my own classes to wrap the validation logic.  I wrote my own classes to encapsulate things more object-oriented way. But it'd be nice if those pydantic models used normal instance method and allowed to pass extra content. It would save writing wrapping code or using global vars. Anyway, thank you for your input!